# Picasso only loading a few images

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to pass a URL to be converted to a bitmap to be used in the activity. I have a class of "Projects" and everything loads fine from the API, including the String Url for the image.

My code looks like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_discover);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            adapter.add(new CardModel(mProject.mName, mProject.mTagline, bitmap));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.d("ISSUE:: ", "IMAGE NOT LOADED");
        }
    };

    adapter = new SimpleCardStackAdapter(this);
    mController = new Controller(this);
    mController.startFetchingProjects();

}

@Override
public void onFetchProgress(Project project) {
    mProjectList.add(project);
    mImageUrls.add(project.mImageUrl);

}


@Override
public void onFetchComplete() {


    for (int i = 0; i < mProjectList.size(); i++){
        mProject = mProjectList.get(i);
        mImage = mImageUrls.get(i);
        Picasso.with(this).load(mImage).into(target);
    }
  }

}
```

For some reason even though there are 24 projects, when I try to load an image, it returns only about 8 random images (the rest go through onPrepareLoad for some reason). If I adapt my projects with no images, I'll have 24 projects, but when I include this picasso method, I only get about 8 images returned, and thus only 8 projects returned. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'd be surprised if Picasso didn't cancel any pending requests for your `Target` as soon as you use the `Target` for a new request. Just compare that to loading 24 images into the same `ImageView`... Try to use a new instance of the `Target` for each image. But keep strong references to each of them, e. g. put them in a `List` and remove them once the loading for that `Target` is completed.

Comment: @david.mihola this actually did fix the issue, but it moved extremely slow. I ended up making a custom adapter that made everything much faster